# pronunciation of PYRamid vs. pyRAMidal

Tags: pronunciation, stress

This recently came up in my geometry class: why is *pyramid* pronounced PIR-uh-mid, while *pyramidal* is pronounced pi-RAM-idal?

From what I can tell, they both have similar roots and etymologies, so what gives?

Comment: English doesn't like the stress to fall on the preantepaenultimate syllable of it can be avoided, that simple. Compare _MIracle/miRAculous_, _eVANgelist/evanGELical_, etc.

Comment: That's not only with "pyramid". There are many similar examples.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That’s because we want **some** sort of stress every two or three syllables, or else we get lost. Such things also annoy the poets, who can’t figure out what kind of feet to make of them. :)

Comment: @tchrist Excepting inflection and inflection-like derivation, of course, where it's tolerated (like _tolerated_, for instance).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Inflexions get a bye, true, but just how often do you really get to talk about *“superproparoxitonic* —well, or *preproparoxitonic* if you prefer— stress” anyway?  Even languages with strong rules about obligatory stress on one of the last three syllables (often) have exceptions for enclitics, like the *informándonoslo* or *chúpamela* of Spanish and the equivalents in Portuguese. BTW, the last clitic in such *“palabras sobresdrújulas”* **does** sometimes seem to have a new, emphatic stress in speech, even though noöne ever writes *demelá* for *démela* except in eye-dialect.

Comment: Next contemplate: photograph, photographer, photographic.

Comment: Even sticking with geometrical solids, you can see a similar shift at work with _cylinder_, _cylindrical_.

Comment: @GEdgar Brilliant example! I was having trouble thinking of any good ones, but _photograph[er/ical]_ is absolutely brilliant to show that stress movement is very common in English.

Comment: @Janus: Uh, just go through the words in the question. *Geometry/geometrical*, *pronounce/pronunciation*, *similar/similarity*, *etymology/etymological*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I meant specifically ones where three or more different stress patterns are found in the same chain of derivation. Two is ubiquitous, I just couldn't think of any with three. Unless you count more distant and questionable derivation, like _Etymon -> etyMOlogy -> etymoLOgical -> etymologiCAlity -> etymologicaliTAtion_, etc. But that's nearing the ridiculous.

Comment: @Janus oh, I see. Well anyway, it's a valid example that fits just fine. "From what I can tell, they all have similar roots and etymologies, so what gives?" If it's nearing the ridiculous, all the better. Goes to show how completely boring *pyramid* vs. *pyramidal* is, and how little sense it makes to single it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a preference for stress on the antepenultimate syllable for words ending with:

- -cy, -ty, -phy and -gy (*PHOtograph* but *phoTOGraphy*)
- -al
- -ise (-ize) (*SUpervise*)
- -ate (*CALculate*)

Therefore, we say *COLlege* but *colLEGial*, *HIStory* but *hisTORical*, *MEDicine* but *meDIcinal*. *PYramid* and *pyRAMidal* is part of the regular pattern of stress assignment according to the ending of the word.